# TaskManager: Process is Terminated At Exactly 2 Hours

Tags: python, windows, process, task

I'm running a python script remotely from a task machine and it creates a process that is supposed to be running for 3 hours. However, it seems to be terminating prematurely at exactly 2 hours. I don't believe it is a problem with the code because after the while loop ends, I am logging to a log file. The log file doesn't show that it exits out of that while loop successfully. Is there a specific setting on the machine that I need to look into that's interrupting my python process?

Answer (score 0):

Is this perhaps a Scheduled Task? If so, have you checked the task's properties? 
On my Windows 7 machine under the "Settings" tab is a checkbox for "Stop the task if it runs longer than:" with a box where you can specify the duration.
One of the suggested durations on my machine is "2 hours."

Comment: It's not a scheduled task. It's executed on the fly